# cakephp populate HABTM select box in EDIT form

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp's form for an HABTM relationship between User and Event.  There is a join table events_users.  The form works well for the Add form, but not for the edit form.  The code is:

Controller:

```
$this->data = $this->Event->findById($id);
```

Form field:

```
$this->Form->input('User');
```

What I get is a blank, input box.  Unlike the select box in the Add form.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to populate a select box with the right Users selected for the input on the edit form?

Comment: What's in your `$this->data`? And more important, what do you want? A select box with the current user selected?

Comment: $this->data when I do a print_r has the Event data, but under "User" it has nothing.  Just User ().  Yes - that's what I want -- a select box with the users (there can be more than one) selected.

Comment: I can't answer my own question for 24 hours, but I figured it out. I modified the controller to use this instead:

`$this->data=$this->Event->findById($id);
$users = $this->Event->User->find('list');
$this->set(compact('data','users'));`
It works.

Comment: And that's indeed the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I modified the controller to use this instead:

```
$this->data=$this->Event->findById($id);
$users = $this->Event->User->find('list');
$this->set(compact('data','users'));
```

It works.